# Язычок панели управления в iOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

В iOS до 11 если приложение в полноэкранном виде, то если сделать свайп снизу или сверху, то сначала показывается язычок, и потом если за него потянуть, то выдвинется системное окошко, это очень удобно и исключает случайные открытия. 
В iOS11 же убрали этот самый язычок, и если потянуть снизу или сверху, то сразу же открывается системное окошко, что очень неудобно ибо сразу появляется куча случайных открытий, особенно если в приложении используются свайпы вниз/вверх, и особенно если приложение работает в горизонтальном режиме.

Есть возможность вернуть этот язычок при необходимости? Сам эту информацию не нашел, но возможно такая возможность все таки есть..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для iOS 11 теперь нет разницы приложение в полноэкранном режиме или нет. Вам необходимо указать какое поведение должно быть и в каких частях экрана должны не сразу срабатывать системные жесты.

Необходимо переопределить:

*Swift 5:*

```
override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
    return [.top, .bottom]
}
```

*Swift 3:*

```
override func preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() -> UIRectEdge {
    return [.top, .bottom]
}
```

*Objective-C:*

```
- (UIRectEdge)preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures
```

[Документация](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887512-preferredscreenedgesdeferringsys?language=objc)